# Order the objects in the field ManyToMany

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

gt.tests - ManyToMany field with model Test. I need to sort the tests by this strange algorithm, but the question is different. After all the operations, I get a sorted list of tests and add them to the ManyToMany field. But when I take the value tests from this field, they are displayed in order from the smallest id test to the largest. How do I add tests to this field in my order?

```
    tests = Test.objects.all()
    gt = GroupTest.objects.create(title=name, user=user)

    #code

    import random
    tests_array = []
    tests_go = []

    for reading in ReadingForTest.objects.all():
        if tests.filter(reading=reading).count() != 0:
            tests_array.append(tests.filter(reading=reading))

    tests_list = tests.filter(reading__isnull=True)

    while len(tests_list) > 0:
        number = random.randint(0, 5)
        tests_array.append(tests_list[:number])
        tests_list = tests_list[number:]

    seq = [x for x in range(len(tests_array))]

    random.shuffle(seq)

    for i in seq:
        tests_go.extend(tests_array[i])

    tests_go = tests_go[:number_of_questions]

    print_arr = []
    for test in tests_go:
        print_arr.append(test.id)
        gt.tests.add(test)

    print(print_arr)
    print([x.id for x in gt.tests.all()])
```

Screenshot output [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZsdZ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a through model.

Sample usage of a through model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    value = models.TextField()

class Test(models.Model)
    value = models.TextField()
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question, related_name="tests", through="QuestionTest")

class QuestionTest(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sort_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

When inserting into the QuestionTest model you need to specify the sort_field, and when getting the tests related to the question you should use something like this.

```
Question.objects.get(id=1).tests.all().order_by("questiontest__sort_field")
```